# Need to set DataContext of a UserControl from another UserControl both of which are on same WPF page

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My WPF form is using multiple user controls. These represents unique forms. I need to give navigational kind of functionality.

Once a user clicks on EDIT button which is on UserControl A, I want to bind DataContext of UserControl B and Open this user control on master form.

This master form contains both the user control. How can I do that?

This is how my code looks like

```
<Window>
        <TabControl  Background="Transparent">
            <TabItem Header="View Registration" Background="Transparent">
                <my:BulkPersonRegistration x:Name="BulkPersonRegistrationForm" />
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Add/Update Person" Background="Transparent">
                <my:PersonManager x:Name="PersonManagerForm" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
</Window>
```

BulkPersonRegistration user control calls a function for data binding to display a datagrid. Upon binding of a datagrid, edit button appears after every row. When user clicks edit button, I want PersonManager form to be binded by the object of edited row.
Problem is, BulkPersonRegistration form is not aware of PersonManagerForm. So I need a way to find out Parent form of BulkPersonRegistration i.e. Owner form and then find Personmanager form and finally setting it's data context. I think all of this needs to be done on BulkRegistration form. I would prefer doing this on Window rather than user control.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using a View Model or code behind?

Comment: I am using code behind. Didn't explored to much on View Model yet due to time constraint.

Comment: What about your master form having a single `ContentControl`, and simply changing the `ContentTemplate` depending on if you are editing or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout along these lines...

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
            Content ="EDIT" 
            Height="30" 
            Width="150"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
            />
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="Control1" DataContext="{Binding}" Background="Yellow"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="Control2" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Green"/>
    <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Rectangle>
</DockPanel>
```

And in the click handler, you can set the data context of the second control...

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Control2.DataContext = Control1.DataContext;
    Control2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This snippet makes the second control visible and makes the first control share its data context with the second control.  You can actually set the control's data context to anything, but this snippet assumes it's the same data context.  Setting the control's visibility will make it 'open'.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can achieve this simply by Binding using **ElementName** like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1"/>
    <local:UserControl2 Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=uc1}"/>
</Grid>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: "Once a user clicks on EDIT button..."

Comment: @ethicallogistics, I read it as the binding should occur within the click event, and the same clicking event should handle the 'Open' of the second control.  In your solution there's no click handler and the second control is always visible.

Comment: write the logic of Visibility in Click event and let the DataContext be same as i did in answer. There is no need to set DataContext again and again in Click Event.

Comment: @ethicallogistics, what if the data context is set to something else prior to the click event?  Or the data context of the first control is not statically declared?

Comment: You want DataContext of Second UC same as first. So just do It in binding. If you dont assign the DataContext to UC1 then it will have same dataContext as that of Window.Binding is dynamic . Means if your DataContex for UC1 is null then the DataContext for UC2 will be null. whenever you will assign the DataContext to Uc1 the DataContext of UC2 will be automatically changed.