# how to make listbox elements as selected from DataContext when ListBox is binded from code behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am trying to set some of the ListBox elements as selected when binding through DataContext. ListBox is binded through code behind.

I am binding my listbox on user control's constructor

```
TradesListBox.ItemsSource = config.OfType<Trade>().ToList();
```

XAML below is a part of UserControl whose DisplayMemberPath property is being set through a constructor as shown in line above, while I am trying to set SelectedItem property from DataContext that is being passed through owing window. But SelectedItem are not being displayed

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Target="{Binding ElementName=TradesListBox}" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right">_Trades</Label>
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="TradesListBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" Margin="2" DisplayMemberPath="ConfigValue" SelectedItem="{Binding Trade.ConfigValue}" SelectionMode="Multiple" />

private List<Trade> trade;
[DataMember]
public virtual List<Trade> Trade
{
    get
    {
        if (trade == null)
            trade = new List<Trade>();
        return trade; 
    }
    set
    { trade = value == null ? new List<Trade>() : value; }
}
```

Comment: Post some relevant code and XAML.

Comment: What is the selected value being bound to?  Also the list box needs to be synched up

Comment: Is the data context here shared with the same data context here?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17899868/1042344

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you are using MVVM then you can bind SelectedItem of ListBox like

> xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ListBox>
```

.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "abc", Age = 20 });
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "pqr", Age = 30 });
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "xyz", Age = 40 });
        SelectedStudent = Students[0];
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    Student selectedStudent;
    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return selectedStudent; }
        set { selectedStudent = value; Notify("SelectedStudent"); }
    }


    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

> CustomType

```
public class Student:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;
    public string Name {
        get
        { return name; }

        set
        {
            name = value;
            Notify("Name");
        }
    }


    int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get
        { return age; }

        set
        {
            age = value;
            Notify("Age");
        }
    }


    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Remember the reference of SelectedItem must be same as that one of the item in Collection binded to ItemsSource** 
**>Edit**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="TradesListBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
Height="70" Margin="2" DisplayMemberPath="ConfigValue" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Trade.ConfigValue}" 
SelectedValuePath="ConfigValue" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Comment: How can I bind set SelectedItem if references are not same?

Comment: Then you will have to use SelectedValue

Comment: SelectedValue didn't work either. I had to capture DataContextChange event to manually set SelectedItems.Add property.

Comment: I just have seen you edited your question. Now there are two mistakes one use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem and other when you bind SelectedValue then you must specify SelectedValuePath property

Comment: No, It didn't work. I binded to SelectedValuePath as SelectedMemberPath property do not exists for ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

I think items are selected but not highlighted, if so then try to set Focus on ListBox and see if it works for you.

```
TradesListBox.ItemsSource = config.OfType<Trade>().ToList();

// Let say you want to Select first and second item
TradesListBox.SelectedItems.Add(TradesListBox.Items[0]);
TradesListBox.SelectedItems.Add(TradesListBox.Items[1]);

// Set focus on ListBox
TradesListBox.Focus();
```